# De Euro a Dolar en Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy con mi último ejercicio de 35 y este me tiene loco!

```
function deEuroAdolar(euro){
  //Supongamos que 1 euro equivale a 1.20 dólares. Escribe un programa que reciba
  //como parámetro un número de euros y calcule el cambio en dólares.
  //Escribe tu código aquí
 
}
```

Alguien sabe de algún articulo o algo donde encontrar información al respecto? no se me ocurre como resolverlo! gracias!

Comment: La idea de los ejercicios es intentarlo, digo yo. Procura ofrecer un ejemplo mínimo verificable.

Comment: Si este ejercicio es el número 35, y no se te ocurre cómo resolverlo, no quiero ni imaginarme cómo serán los otros 34 de básicos que no te han enseñado ni a realizar una simple multiplicación dentro de la función con un return del resultado. Usa jsfiddle.net para tus pruebas y usa console.log() para extraer resultados parciales en la consola (que debes abrir bajo el cuadrado blanco de la salida), y se te abrirá un mundo nuevo para la depuracion fácil en javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Tendrías que hacer una regla de 3 pero como en este caso el divisor seria 1 no hace falta, lo solucionas con una multiplicación.

**Ejemplo**

```js
function deEuroAdolar(euro){
    //Supongamos que 1 euro equivale a 1.20 dólares. Escribe un programa que reciba
    //como parámetro un número de euros y calcule el cambio en dólares.
    //Escribe tu código aquí
    let resultado = euro * 1.2;
    console.log(resultado);
  }
  
deEuroAdolar(20);
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si tu pregunta ha sido resuelta por favor marca como resuelta la respuesta gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Lo básico es hacer una regla de tres, pero antes debes capturar la cantidad de euros que el usuario quiera convertir a dólares...

También recién comienzo en esto de JS, lo resolví de la siguiente manera, espero te sirva. Saludos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>De Euro a Dolar</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Covertir de Euro a Dolar</h1>
    <input id="txtEuro" type="text" placeholder="Cuántos euros quieres convertir"> Euros
    <p>
        <input id="botoncito" type="button" value="Convertir">
    </p>

    <script>
        var numeroDeEuros = document.getElementById("txtEuro");
        var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
        
        function deEuroAdolar()
        {

            var euro = 1.2; // 1 Euro equivale a 1.2 dolares

            resultado = euro * parseInt(numeroDeEuros.value);
            alert(resultado + " dolares");
        }

        boton.addEventListener("click", deEuroAdolar);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero las respuestas con solo código no son bien aceptadas por la comunidad. Léete [answer] y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y cómo elaborar una buena respuesta. Puedes [edit] tu respuesta para agregar una breve explicación de porque crees que esta respuesta contesta correctamente a la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @masterguru, ya edité el comentario y me leí los hilos que me sugieres.